# How should I choose corn?

Tags: fresh, corn, produce

What should I look for when I'm buying corn on the cob? We have a lot of roadside corn stands where we live, and I'm never sure how to pick the best ears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very fresh, ripe ear of corn will have a moist, green, unblemished husk; when peeled back, its silk will also moist and clinging to the kernels. In the store, you may find that an ear of corn will have a slightly dried out husk, but if it's still green and the kernels look plump when the husk is pulled back, that ear's fine. Ignore any husks that are very dry with rotten-looking, off-smelling silk tops.

Comment: Also it should be firm to the touch with no breaks in the outer husk